# Outlook rules: how to move old emails from specific email address?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I know how to create a rule to move a copy of specific email to specific folder, but that only moves the upcoming emails. How can I move the old emails as well from the same email address?

Comment: Just search for *all* mail by *address*, or sort each folder by address and drag/drop those desired.

Answer (score 0):

On Outlook go to a folder where are the messages, select one of specific mails, right click, Rules, Create Rule, select appropriate fields, Advanced options,  next, next, next, select Run this rule now..... (see the image)
[image]

In my case the source folder is "Sent Items"

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, it is an expect behavior.
You need Go to click **Rules > Manage Rules** > Double-click the rule you created,
and click **Next > Next > Next** > Check the option "**Run this rule now already in "Inbox**" > **Finish**

[image]

Then click **Apply** to save the rule.

If that doesn't work, you can delete the rule, and use [Always move messages from a specific sender](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/always-move-messages-from-a-specific-sender-e28d03c0-077d-4366-a348-4536f0fc9008), it creates a rule that applies to all current and future messages.

Hope above may help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.